# dpkg won't update - input/output error in indicator-session

Tags: dpkg

I have been having an error trying to update my system. Currently I can't install/remove or update anything with apt-get...

Here is the error I get when running apt-get update

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'indicator-session': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 13.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install any updates through update manager/apt-get upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139377/unable-to-install-any-updates-through-update-manager-apt-get-upgrade)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I looked around some more and found a solution: It is in this post: 
[Unable to install any updates through update manager/apt-get upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139377/unable-to-install-any-updates-through-update-manager-apt-get-upgrade)

There is a link in the answer to this page: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1232143.html

It comes down to editing the /var/lib/dpkg/status file and removing everything related to the broken package.

My system is up and running again!

Comment: I've been unable to fix this problem for such a long time and just not installed anything. This helped!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the output I got from `apt-get`:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libecryptfs0' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libplexus-containers1.5-java' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `apport' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
```

And this is how I fixed it:

1. Backup the dpkg status file:

   ```sh
   cp /var/lib/dpkg/status{,.backup}
   ```
2. Edit the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file¹  and remove the sections for the packages that `apt-get` printed warnings about. Make sure that you remove the whole section about these packages, i. e. starting with the line `Package: libecryptfs0` down to the first blank line.

   Alternatively you can use `sed` to do the work for you:

   ```sh
   sed -i.backup -e '/^Package: \(libecryptfs0\|libplexus-containers1\.5-java\|apport\)$/,/^$/d' /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

   This command deletes all sections between and including the lines with `Package: <PACKAGE_NAME>` and the next empty line. You can place any valid package names between the parentheses `\(…\)`, delimit them with `\|`, and escape the dots (`.` → `\.`). The option `-i.backup` edits the file in place and creates a backup file suffixed with `.backup` (so you can skip step 1 if you use variant) instead of writing the result to stdout.
3. Run `sudo apt-get -f install` to configure unconfigured packages and (re-)install missing package. The packages are missing because we removed them from the `status` file.

¹ See [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](/q/92379/175814) for how to that.