# meld installation issue

Tags: installation, package-management, diff

I am trying to install the meld diff viewer on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I run

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common python-glade2 python-gnome2 python-gtksourceview2
  python-pyorbit
Suggested packages:
  python-gtk2-doc python-gnome2-doc libgtksourceview2.0-dev python-pyorbit-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common meld python-glade2 python-gnome2
  python-gtksourceview2 python-pyorbit
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,048 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,255 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Selecting previously unselected package libgtksourceview2.0-common.
(Reading database ... 60%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
reading files list for package 'python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Is there something wrong with the package `libgtksourceview2.0-common`? Is there a way to get a better update, or another way to get meld installed? I am uncertain how to proceed...

Comment: Did you tried with `aptitude`: `sudo aptitude install meld`?

Comment: Your command syntax is unfamiliar to me. Normally when using the advanced package tool it is "apt-get". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets`

Comment: reinstallation of the package gives the same error again.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unable to install any updates through update manager/apt-get upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139377/unable-to-install-any-updates-through-update-manager-apt-get-upgrade)

Comment: Note that the [Meld package in the Ubuntu repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/meld) is about **2 years behind** the [current version](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/refs/tags).

Answer (score 2):

I just tried installing Meld on my 12.04 installation, using `sudo apt-get install meld`, and it worked with no problems.

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install meld
```

If that dosen't work, try installing the latest python

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: The upgrade failed with the same error (at 60% dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error). And I do not want to install python3 yet, I'm doing a project that requires 2.7 and I already have a side installation of 3.3.1. Is there any way to exploit that?

Comment: Note that the [Meld package in the Ubuntu repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/meld) is about **2 years behind** the [current version](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/refs/tags).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the package, the install on my 12.04 system worked just fine.  Try to update your dateabase first, then do the  install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install meld
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I had already run update. I re-ran update but still the same error as described above.

Comment: 2017 update: note that the [Meld package in the Ubuntu 16 (Xenial) repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/meld) is about **2 years behind** the [current version](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/refs/tags).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo aptitude install meld`.

If you are not familiar with `aptitude`, check this post: [Aptitude vs. apt-get: Which is the recommended (aka the “right”) tool to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use)

> `aptitude` and `apt-get` work the same for many tasks, but for the most tricky cases, such as distribution upgrades (apt-get dist-upgrade vs. aptitude full-upgrade), they have different rules, and aptitude's rules are nearly always better in practice where they disagree.

If you don't have installed `aptitude`, use `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: I read the other post. My take is that although aptitude has some advantages, it did not seem to be a universal preference. Regardless, the upgrade itself failed with the same error (see comment in Mitch's answer)

Comment: You may not want to "just use `sudo aptitude install meld`. The [Meld package in the Ubuntu repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/meld) is about **2 years behind** the [current version](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/refs/tags).