# Software Center installation gives - E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: package-management, software-center, dpkg

Ubuntu 16.04

I know there are several similar questions and answers but they seem to be specific for the file that triggers the error, in my case as below.

```
Selecting previously unselected package python-dbus.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

also

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

gives the above error every time
thanks for any assistance

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get autoclean`?

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe - still the same -  autoclean runs ok - no errors - but have original problem

Comment: Alright, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139377/unable-to-install-any-updates-through-update-manager-apt-get-upgrade) please, and report back.

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe - should I delete the entire linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic section or leave the title there

Comment: Delete the entire section for that package.

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe sorry - quite new to Ubuntu - says I am not owner and will not allow me to save edited file

Comment: In a terminal, use `sudo nano` to get edit rights for that file, and to open the `nano` file editor.

Comment: hi sorry i have not wanted to give you too much work so i have been struggling with my basic knowledge - I now have access to the file but cannot get my head around  nano, the user interface is very confusing.  I can use gedit gut there seems to be no search function.  I could use LibreWriter but am scared it may not save it as a text file.  I have tried with gedit but i need a search facility the file is massive

Comment: ok finally conquered my demons - used my html editor in the end, that seems to have worked - thanks so much - if you post it as an answer i can accept it

Comment: still got my original problem though - even after re-installing Software Center it is still empty - resigning myself to living without it